# Write Date Time in file one by one using powershell or visual studio

Tags: powershell-3.0

Hello friends i need your help to automate a process I have two Directories like ***Directory A And Directory B***

- In Directory A i have Folder which is having 10-20 xml files with name like (A,B,C,D.......Z)
- Now read files one by one from the folder Directory A and write current date/time then move it after to other directory B
- Now Read Second file and write current date/time then move it after to other directory B
- Now Read Third file and write current date/time then move it after to other directory B
- Repeat this steps till the .XML files Exists in Directory A

See the below Code so far i have tried but i am getting *"Missing statement body in foreach loop.*" Error -message

```
$a = Get-Content "D:\*.txt"

foreach ($i in $a) 

get-date | Out-file $a -Append 
foreach ($file in $a)
Move-Item D:\*.txt D:\text
```

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show the code you have tried so far? What's stopping you to achieve this? The site is not about "here is the spec" and "give me the code". What we could help is fixing the code if it doesn't work. Please read about [on topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @YuliamChandra and Soner I was new into this forum and i am new learner of powershell so i was not aware about this. Thanks for correcting me. BTW i have mentioned the code which i have tried so far. Kindly check and help me if possible. thanks

Comment: I removed the `c#` tag, this question doesn't seem to have any relation with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Get-ChildItem` to list all files instead of `Get-Content` and you can just use one foreach and wrap them with curly braces.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem "D:\A\*.txt"
foreach ($i in $a) {
    if ($i) {
        Get-Date | Out-File $i -Append -encoding ASCII
        Move-Item $i "D:\B" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried your above code and i am not getting correct output i am getting null text instead of date time see the below url for more info

http://i.stack.imgur.com/lj466.jpg)

Comment: Thanks my Friend for your kind help. your code is working but the problem which i am still facing with above code is "Its adding date and time in the file" but here i want to overwrite the files. Means its existing content should be erased

Comment: @404fnf, if you want to overwrite it, you can omit the `-Append` parameter